# Refresh a Block content when the page refreshes using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, refresh, drupal-blocks

I Just wanna change the content of my block when the page refreshes(Just like the concept in advertisement block changes on page refresh).I'm doing a drupal7 site.That block is a dynamic one (views:block) it has four fields of three text and one image field.
The block's content belongs to a content type "X".On the page refresh the block should show one of content of content type "X".
I want to change the content of the block whenever the page refresh takes place.
Could you please give me the guidance for the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again I don't thank you need a script for this. I guess we can do this by setting the "Items per page" in view to 1 and and in sort criteria select "Global: Random". This should randomize the display of content in the block on every page refresh.

Comment: @Aneesh.Thanks for your reply ,Aneesh.I may not convey my requirement in my question but now i edited it so please let me know if this is clear.And give me answer if you know...